# Problems with Typo3 multilanguage website

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I am pretty new in Typo3 world.

I am working on this multilanguage website: http://www.fao.org/investment/investment-policy/investment-policy-support-home/en/ of which I have renovated the home page inserting an HTML module and creating some static content into it. Infact if you try to click on a language that is different from the english, still appear the english version homepage

I have a problem: the website is a multilanguage website but I can't show 3 different home page version (english verion, french version and spanish version).

I have do the following operation:

1. In the Typo3 backend I have selected my home page and (selecting the **Default value for the Language field of the page** I have inserted a **Plain HTML** element in the central columns. Then I have insert my custom HTML code in this module selecting  **Default value for the Language field of this Plain HTML module**
2. then I have do the same operations for french and spanish version (inserting the right content) selecting the **Francais** value for the Language field of the page** and selecting**Francais value for the Language field of this Plain HTML module**

But in this way don't work and for any chosen language content appears in English.

Why? Where is the problem? How can I solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Did you *localize* the content for the french and spanish languages, or did you only create additional content elements for these languages? If you did the latter one, try localizing the first, english content element. You can do so in the "List"-module, after switching on the "localization"-view (checkbox at the bottom).

Comment: Hello I ask your support because I am a Typo3 beginner and I have not create this website but I am only working on it (the site has been created by someone else in the past and the old content are alredy localized). So, if I understand what you mean, I have to localize my new content. Is it right? I am trying to do what you say to me and I have do the following operation: 1) I go in the List view backend module, 2) I switch to the "localization view clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: 3) Here I say some "Headers" with the language flags, between these Headers I can see my HomePage headers that have the following settings: its Localization field is setted to "Default" and its Localize field have inside 3 flags: francais, spanish an japanese. What have I to do now?

Comment: When you click on one of the flags (They are in a column "localize to" or similar), a localized version of the content element is created and the editor for it is opened.